App Store Connect: Remove From Sale vs Remove App affect on Existing Users
Clicking "Remove from Sale" in the iOS App Store Connect "Pricing and Availability" tab makes the app not visible in the App Store but people who have previously downloaded the app can still keep it on their device and even see it in the list of downloaded apps.  This is the current state of one of my apps.
I need to free up the name of the the app to use it on a new app of mine and so I need to go to the App Information tab and click "Remove App".  Once I do this, will previous user still be able to use the previously downloaded app like they could when it was merely removed from sale? (This is what I want - I don't want to interrupt legacy users.) Is it effectively the same thing to the end user as "Remove from Sale"?
